# Check and create lost GameObjects from code (not during gameplay)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok. When I open my project if someone `GameObject` (or all of them) is not found then it should be created automatically.
For example, I have `SceneBuilder` as `GameObject` and it contains all necessary scripts: `ObjectsGenerator.cs`, `PlayerData.cs` etc. And if somehow `SceneBuilder` disappears it must be recover from code. How can I do that?

p.s.: I found only two ways:

- creating it from menu `[MenuItem("MyTools/CreateGameObjects")]`, but it not obviously for support.
- creating it through `[CustomEditor(typeof(SomeOjectScript))]` , but it must be already exists in scene (I guess a situation where the scene is completely empty)

p.s.: sorry if the question has already been and I have not found it

```
updated.
```

thanks to all. solved something like that

```
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class Checker : MonoBehaviour
{
    static Checker()
    {
        CheckAndCreateObj();
        EditorApplication.hierarchyChanged += hierarchyChanged;
    }

    private static void hierarchyChanged()
    {
        CheckAndCreateObj();
    }

    private static void CheckAndCreateObj()
    {
        string objName = "OBJECTNAME";
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find(objName);

        if (go == null)
        {
            Instantiate(new GameObject(objName));
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html

Comment: you can use the `InitializeOnLoad` attribute on a class with static constructor (refert to link below). if you only want it on launching the editor and not each time you enter and exit play mode check against `EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode` https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check it dynamicly in one of your other scripts. You can call it from `OnEnable` or `Start` functions. Your MonoBehaviour must contain tag `[ExecuteInEditMode]` It could be something like this:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class YourMonoBehaviour: MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnEnable()
    {
        var myObject = GameObject.Find("GAMEOBJECT_NAME");
        if (myObject == null)
        {
            //Create new GameObject here and add your Component
        }
    }
}
```

If you need save some asset links or data in your gameobject with serialization, you can create prefab, cache it and create your object from prefab:

```
MyObjectType prefabTemplate;

void OnEnable()
{
    if (GameObject.Find("GAMEOBJECT_NAME") == null)
    {
        GameObject.Instantiate(prefabTemplate);
    }
}
```